# get today data from room database

Tags: kotlin, date, android-room

**get dates data from room database**

> i have created task db class as below

```
   @ColumnInfo(name = "task_start_date") var taskStartDate: Date?,
@ColumnInfo(name = "task_end_date") var taskEndDate: Date?,
@ColumnInfo(name = "task_never_end") var taskNeverEnd: Boolean?
       @PrimaryKey
    var tid: Long?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "task_title") var TaskTitle: String?
```

> I do insert data with below function

```
    fun getTodayDate(): Date {
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    return GregorianCalendar(
        calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
        calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
        calendar.get(Calendar.DATE),
        calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
        calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
        calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND)
    ).time
}
```

> fetching data with below codes and params todayDate = above functio getTodayDate()

```
@Query("select * from task where task_start_date =:todayDate ")
fun getTodayTask(todayDate: Date): List<Task>
```

> with above implementation I m getting 0 result
> I assume room is converting date to long and stores and also compare with long value so this thing never gonna match
> **so can u please help me out how to get task that only matched dates not time**

**example**

**I have inserted data for 11-09-2022 12:00:00 PM,11-09-2022 1:00:00 PM,11-09-2022 2:00:00 PM,11-09-2022 3:00:00 PM,11-09-2022 4:00:00 PM in the form of Date object not string.
now I want to fetch all task that match only date like 11-09-2022 not time**

**Converter**

```
class TimestampConverter {


@TypeConverter
fun fromTimestamp(value: Long?): Date? {
    return value?.let { Date(it) }
}

@TypeConverter
fun dateToTimestamp(date: Date?): Long? {
    return date?.time
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that java times when converted to long include milliseconds so you need to strip of the milliseconds,seconds,minutes and hours.

You can divide both sides of the argument by 1000 (milliseconds) * 60 (seconds per minute) * 60 (minutes per hour) * 24 (hours per day)  (i.e. **86,400,000** milliseconds per day) and this will strip of the time and the comparison will be at the date level.

So try:-

```
@Query("select * from task where task_start_date / 86400000 =:todayDate / 86400000 ")
```

Regarding the comment:-

> how could this possible ? ex : I got milliseconds 1662899658575 and divide by 86400000. so result would be 19246.5238261.

Here is a demonstration that shows/explains using SQLite (which room is a wrapper around).

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS example;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example (timestamp);
INSERT INTO example VALUES(1662899658575);
SELECT 
    timestamp, /* The actual stored value */
    strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',timestamp/1000,'unixepoch') AS date, /* Using SQLite strftime function to extract the exact date time (less milliseconds) */
    timestamp / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) AS `daysSince1:1:1970`, /* the number of days since 1/1/1970 (based upon the unix date/time) i.e. the date part only*/
    (timestamp / (86400000 /* drop millisecs*/ * 365 /* drop years*/)) + 1970 /* add to start */ AS year /* The year factoring in unix datetime starting 1/1/1970 */
    FROM example
;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS example; /* Cleanup Environment*/
```

When run the columns output are:-

[image]

As can be seen

```
- 1662899658575 / 86400000 = 19246 which equates to the date as it is the number of days since 1/1/1970 and thus represents the date 2022-09-11 according to unix datetime
```

You may be interested in:-

> In computing, Unix time (also known as Epoch time, Posix time,[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hipyX.png) seconds since the Epoch,[2] Unix timestamp or UNIX Epoch time[3]) is a system for describing a point in time. It is the number of seconds that have elapsed since the Unix epoch, excluding leap seconds. The Unix epoch is 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970.

> Unix time is not a true representation of UTC, because a leap second and the second before it have the same Unix time (or after it, implementation dependent). Put differently, every day in Unix time contains exactly 86400 seconds;[2] no seconds added to or subtracted from the day as a result of positive or negative leap seconds.

> Unix time originally appeared as the system time of Unix, but is now used widely in computing, for example by filesystems; some Python language library functions handle Unix time.[4]

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time
- https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: how could this possible ? ex : I got milliseconds 1662899658575 and divide by 86400000.
so result would be **19246.5238261**.

Comment: @unknown obviously you have not tried, rather you have just got a calculator and said what is **19246**.5238261.  First as the vales are Long then the result will be an integer not decimal. So 19246, divide that by 365 (days in a year) and the result is 52 (integer). The unix time starts 1/1/1970 so 2022 is 52 years from 1970.  Adding an example.

Comment: yes i taken two different column startDateTime & startDate(timeInMillis / 1000)  & with this startDate Column i have set hour,minute,second to 0 so long value i get the same for a particular day. Thannk You

Comment: i have issue which is related to query result of two tables '@Query("select * from catmodel c JOIN tagmodel t where c.title=:value OR t.tag_title =:value"):List<JoinData>'  this query return 0 ALWAYS   and class as 'data class JoinData( @Embedded
                     val title: CatModel,
                     val tag_title: TagModel)'  . can you help me with this issue.